# Can you have an overall probabilistic many body quantum system with deterministic body mechanics but probabilistic interaction mechanics among them?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, many-body, determinism, randomness

I try to understand if it is possible a quantum many body system in total to have a **probabilistic** time independent behavior (not stochastic which has a time-depended evolution) but with its elements (i.e. bodies) having and being described by deterministic mechanics? These would infer that only their interactions among them are described by probabilistic mechanics but the bodies itself are deterministic having some fixed value intrinsic properties.

Assuming this is a quantum many body system and is not decohered into macroscopic would this system overall exhibit probabilistic mechanics and behavior (i.e. Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle, non-locality etc.)?

Simply put, can you have a probabilistic system behavior with its parts being deterministic objects?

OR

Such a system is not possible and why? Both physical and mathematical explanations are welcome.

Comment: Why I've asked this question? Because I am investigating the option of describing single elementary particles at rest and without translational linear motion as having deterministic intrinsic mechanics resulting to their fixed value intrinsic properties like charge, mass, magnetic moment etc. but when in translational motion are interacting with probabilistic mechanics, would resolve the Measurement Problem?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it is my logical conclusion that a closed system in order to be probabilistic and not totally random MUST by definition include some  deterministic terms-elements. These deterministic terms are the very reason why the overall behavior of the system is probabilistic (i.e. Gaussian Curve) and not totally random (i.e. white flat noise).
Is this not mathematically the main difference between probabilistic and total random?